# How to obtain JTable header text on two line

Tags: java, jtable

In a JTable, is possibile to have the text of header on 2 or more lines?

Something like this:

[image]

I tried something like:

```
getModel().getColumn(i).setHeaderValue("first word" + "\n" + "Second word");
```

but what I get is this:

[image]

Comment: A wild guess: Usually, Swing support HTML (not sure whether it works for JTable headers as expected, though), so you might try `"<html>first word<br>Second word</html>"`. If it doesn't work, drop a note, then there are probably other options.

Comment: @Marco13 thank you man, I didn't know it (this is the first time I workwith Swing). You really helped me :)

Comment: So then I think the other question covers this pretty well. Closing as a duplicate. Drop me a note if you think this is not OK:

Comment: In case someone had my same problem: according  to what another user told me, swing has the HTML 3.2 engine, so I used a <table> (because I had to force every line not to break), with <td nowrap>.